# Jenkins Run Shell Script after Email Sent

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When job build finishes, the Jenkins will trigger the email with the attachment on the Linux server. But after the email is sent, I want to delete the attachment by running shell script again. I use `Editable Email` plug in to send email.

Is there a way to do that ?

Note: shell script should not run immediately after the job finished, but after job finished as well as email sent.

Comment: You can achieve this by using pipeline instead of a freestyle job. While you can trigger another job that will delete the attachment, I think this is clunkier as the workflow is artificially split between two jobs and it will be a more fragile solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Post-Build task plug-in: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task

The pipeline is a better way of doing this, however, if you are comfortable with Free-Style job, then it's better you drag and re-arrange the post-build task to do a specific task.

You can also do the certain task if your job is success/failure by checking the logs against specific keyword etc. Please follow plugin page for more info.